# Does URLSession upload task configured for background operation execute during a phone call

Tags: swift, background, core-location, nsurlsession, phone-call

I am writing an application that is enabled for background operation for location updates. The intent is to allow a person to setup geofences which triggers a Twilio SMS message upon an entry or exit event.

I've played around with several settings and currently am only using the following settings for the session:

```
configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: Constants.twilioBackgroundSessionIdentifier)

    configuration.isDiscretionary = false

    bgSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    // Build the request
    let completeURL = URL(string: "https://" + Constants.twilioSSLHostName + Constants.twilioSendSMSURL)

    // Create request and https header
    let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: completeURL!)
    req.httpMethod = Constants.httpMethod.post
    req.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

    // Create Twilio required Parms for Send SMS POST
    let countryCode = "+1"
    let httpBodyString = "to=" + countryCode + sendToNumber + "&message=" + message
    //NSLog("Body string: \(httpBodyString)")

    //Need a File for the background uploadTaskWithRequest                          //
    //the request contains the real information                                     //
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let fileName = path + "/Twillio.html"
    var fileURL: URL!

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileName) {
        //Remove the tempory file
        do {
            try fileManager.removeItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName))
        } catch {
            //NSLog("TwilioManager:sendSMS:unable to remove tmp file")
        }
    }
    let remoteSeverValueString : String = httpBodyString

    do {
        try remoteSeverValueString.write(toFile: fileName, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch {
        // failed to write file – bad permissions, bad filename, missing permissions, or more likely it can't be converted to the encoding
        //NSLog("TwilioManager:sendSMS:Unable to write file")
    }
    fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName)

    let contentLength = fileManager.contents(atPath: fileName)!.count

    req.setValue(String(contentLength), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    upLoadTask = bgSession.uploadTask(with: req as URLRequest, fromFile: fileURL)
    // Set task to highest priority
    upLoadTask.priority = 1.0

    upLoadTask.resume()

    bgSession.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

I've gotten improvements in background responsiveness using the .isDiscretionary = false and setting the task.priority to 1.0.

When I am on an active phone call during the location event I don't receive the SMS until I hang up and then it comes immediately (even when the app is in the background). I don't know if the location update or the upload task is being delayed.

I realize Apple frowns upon apps relying on background operation but this is for a person with a disability and allows them to have an app always running that alerts their location to family and friends in realtime.

Is there anything I can do to get the location update and/or upload task to occur during the phone call?

Comment: You can use a standard `URLSession` but use [`beginBackgroundTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtask) to tell the OS that you want to keep the app alive in background for a short period of time (usually 3 minutes) to complete the request (and call [`endBackgroundTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622970-endbackgroundtask) when done). That way you're not subject to the limitations of background `URLSession`. I've never tested it during a phone call, but you might want to try that.

Comment: An unrelated observation on your code snippet: Rather than using `NSMutableURLRequest`, just use `var req = URLRequest(url: ...)`. It saves you from having to do that cast at `uploadTask(...)` (note the `var`, not `let`). There's no reason to introduce the `NS` rendition here.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the suggestion on the var vs let, I will make the change.

Comment: @Rob unfortunately the URLSession gets called while in the background. The didEnterRegion or didExitRegion event fires while in the background and then the delegate makes the URLSession call to talk to a remote server that relays the request to the Twilio server.

Comment: If it's in the background, then it's even worse, because the system doesn't honor the `isDiscretionary` setting. "For transfers started while your app is in the background, the system always starts transfers at its discretion—in other words, the system assumes [`isDiscretionary`] is true and ignores any value you specified."